# Добавление параметров слежения для select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

[image: Пример select'a]

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, я хочу реализовать отслеживание расстояния при попомщи атрибута select.. ТО есть изначально расстояние равняется 10км. Я хочу чтобы слева при одной прокруте убирался один километр, а справа добавлялось по 5 км для каждого смещения элемента вправо.

Возможно ли это как-то сделать? Заранее очень благодарен всем кто поможет.

```html
            <div class="filter__distance">
                <div class="filter__desc">Расстояние</div>
                <div class="filter__distance-item">
                    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" id="size"
                          value="3"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то такое? Реализация на **JQ**

```js
let lastStep = 0;
$('#step').bind('mousemove change', function(){
  let thisStep = $(this).val(), // новый шаг
      rangePosX = thisStep-lastStep;
  // -----
  if(rangePosX<0) { //left;
    $(this).attr('step', '1');
    $('#step_counter').text(thisStep);
  } else if(rangePosX>0) {//right;
    $(this).attr('step', '5');
    $('#step_counter').text(thisStep);
  }
  // -----
  lastStep = $(this).val(); // старый шаг
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="step" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
<br>
<label id="step_counter">50</label>
```

Comment: не вижу в ответе "атрибута select"

Comment: @Igor, а где вы видели **атрибут** select в input range?

Comment: в вопросе - "я хочу реализовать отслеживание расстояния при попомщи атрибута select"

Comment: Извините, я сам перепутал, это решение вполне подходит, спасибо!

Comment: @DaniilLav, не за что)

Comment: А можете подсказать, возможно ли такое что ваш js код работает непосредственно в самом документе, а если его подключать через сторонний js файл то нет? Просто у меня так почему-то(при условии что остальная часть js кода не связанная с этим элементом работает отлично)